# Where to find http returned data using AsyncTask, android network connection

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm using code straight from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) to read a website but i'm not understanding how to access the data within the `myClickHandler` method. The program works and grabs the data fine, but I can only see it in the `DownloadWebpageTask` class. Here is the code section:

So where in `myClickHandler` can I access the data `onPostExecute` produces? Thanks for any help.

```
public class HttpExampleActivity extends Activity {
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
private EditText urlText;
private TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   
    urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myUrl);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
}

public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    // Gets the URL from the UI's text field.
    String stringUrl = urlText.getText().toString();
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
    } else {
        textView.setText("No network connection available.");
    }
}


 private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
   }
}
...
```

}

Comment: Why you and to  access the data within the myClickHandler method? because you can do same task in `onPostExecute` which you want to do in `myClickHandler` ?

Comment: doInBackground executes in another thread, onPostExecute executes in UI thread and has access to the results of the task (String result)

Comment: I just want to know how to access the data from the same method I create the `DownloadWebpageTask`. Seems like I should be able to but I don't know how. Thanks. Does `onPostExecute` have to wait for `doInBackground` to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html to read more about Async Task.

For your question: can I access the data onPostExecute produces?
Ans: Yes, you can access onPostExecute as it Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground.

Does onPostExecute have to wait for doInBackground to complete?
Ans: Yes

AsyncTask has four steps:

1. doInBackground: Code performing long running operation goes in this method.  When onClick method is executed on click of button, it calls execute method 
   which accepts parameters and automatically calls doInBackground method with the parameters passed.
2. onPostExecute: This method is called after doInBackground method completes processing. Result from doInBackground is passed to this method.
3. onPreExecute: This method is called before doInBackground method is called.
4. onProgressUpdate: This method is invoked by calling publishProgress anytime from doInBackground call this method